# php array values matched again arrays keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an string in database : 3,8,10,15

and in script i have an array : `$a=array(0=>'music',1=>'computers'....etc)`, the keys are matching the strings in database.

Then i `explode()` the string from database with: `$a=explode(",",$dbresult)`
This makes an array like this:

```
$a =
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 15
)
```

In script:

```
<?PHP
$b=array(0=>'music',1=>'Computers','...etc');
    $a = explode(",",$a);
    foreach ( $b as $key => $value ){

    $select = $a==$key ? " checked='checked'" : null;

    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='name' value='{$key}'$select/> {$value};
    }}
?>
```

This ofcourse will not work since its matching the $b arrays keys, and not the values of $a

So my question is.. How can i make it match the $b keys against $a values ?

Comment: I'm not understanding the relationship to `$a` and `$b`. Are the keys supposed to align between them such that `$a[0] (3)` is related to `$b[0] (music)`?

Comment: Or do the values of `$a` relate to the keys of `$b` such that `$a[0] (3)` relates to `$b[3] ('someotherthing'`)?

Comment: Yes, the $a is the keys of $b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
<?php
$b = array(0=>'music',1=>'Computers','...etc');
$a = explode(",", '0,3');
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    $select = in_array($key, $a) ? " checked='checked'" : null;

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="' . $key . '"' . $select . '/>';
    echo $value;
}
```